# avoid displaying several divs each on a new line (IE11)

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-11

The user can save some pictures from a list that will be stored in a `div` containing the thumbnails of the saved pictures. I dynamically resize the containing `div` to be big enough to contain all the thumbnails. As long as I use an `img` tag to contain the thumbnails everything works fine, as in the following screenshot:

[image]

The code I use to build the `div`:

```
currentPictures.innerHTML += "<img class='preview' id='spic" + picId + "' " +
            "onclick='showImageOnCanvas(\"" + sourceImg + "\", " + picId + ")' " + 
            "oncontextmenu='removeSavedPicture(\"spic" + picId + "\");' " + 
            "src='" + sourceImg + "'> ";
```

`css` for `.preview`:

```
.preview {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 80px;
    height: 54px;
    border: black 2px solid;
}
```

This is the `css` of the containing `div` (some of this values are changed programmatically according to the number of thumbnails saved):

```
#currentPictures {
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 38px;
    left: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 320px;
    z-index: 16;
    background-color: #DDDDDD;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    padding: 16px 16px 16px 16px;
    border-radius: 6px;

    font-family: arial;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: none;
    overflow-y: none;
    overflow-x: scroll;

    -ms-user-select: none;
```

}

Now I want to put the `img` in a `div`, in order to add some text to the picture. The problem is that as soon as I wrap the `img` in a `div`, the divs are stacked and not put next to each other, as in this screenshot:

[image]

The code:

```
currentPictures.innerHTML += "<div><img class='preview' id='spic" + picId + "' " +
            "onclick='showImageOnCanvas(\"" + sourceImg + "\", " + picId + ")' " + 
            "oncontextmenu='event.preventDefault(); removeSavedPicture(\"spic" + picId + "\");' " + 
            "src='" + sourceImg + "'></div> ";
```

I tried to use different display styles on the div but with no success.

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something obvious. Thanks!

Comment: In case that you are using bootstrap you can try add class="row" to your "currentPictures" div and then add the class col-sm-* and/or col-md-* and/or col-lg-* to the children divs.
Check this link to bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#thumbnails

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using google icons. Thanks for the hint though.